# Account migration from one Marketing Cloud account to another

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have multi-tenant account and I was wondering does anybody have experience with moving in to another stack?
So all the data extensions, automations, cloud pages, connection to sales cloud, ... moving from one account to another.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFSE. Although this is a great topic, questions here need to be specific and need to show a 'good faith' effort. Unfortunately your question does not fit either of those, so I would recommend either editing it to make it more development focused and detailed or look to take this question to a place like the SF success community, howtosfmc or email-geeks which are designed for these more open-ended questions. As it stands, your question is likely to be closed and unanswered.

Comment: You can always use [Deployment Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_deployment_manager.htm&type=5) and/or [Package Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_marketing_cloud_package_manager.htm&type=5) to pack almost everything up. Besides that review many other similar questions on SFSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a stack migration, talk to your AE and Salesforce Support.
if applicable, you can get a document called the Marketing Cloud Tenant Migration Guide.

We (as a partner) have been involved in stack migrations for customers, but the main heavy lifting is on SF side and they should have very good material and practices for you.

You will have a system downtime in which SF performs the necessary tasks.
We did not move anything using Deployment Manager and similar tools ourselves. In our case the downtime was around 6 hours, after which you can go through a "post migration checklist" supplied in the document.

The main thing that will likely occur on your side is checking MC Connect and journey triggers after the migration.
Make sure to document the MC Connect configuration before the change so you can dis- and reconnect if necessary.